# Merge two text files block by block

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two text files each containing a block of text separated by empty lines. The blocks vary in sizes.

```
# ::id 10
# ::snt Yes !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 11
# ::snt said Lion .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 12
# ::snt Yes yes !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 13
# ::snt said Tiger .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...
```

and similarly another

```
# ::id 10
# ::snt No !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...

# ::id 11
# ::snt said Monkey .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...

# ::id 12
# ::snt No no !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...

# ::id 13
# ::snt said Donkey .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...
```

I want to merge the two blocks, but sort them by their `# ::id`. Also, I need to mainain the order of file1 data blocks before file2 data blocks. So final output should be something like:

```
# ::id 10
# ::snt Yes !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 10
# ::snt No !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...

# ::id 11
# ::snt said Lion .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 11
# ::snt said Monkey .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...

# ::id 12
# ::snt Yes yes !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 12
# ::snt No no !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...

# ::id 13
# ::snt said Tiger .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 13
# ::snt said Donkey .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...
```

How do I do it? Anything will work `bash`, `sed`, `awk`

Comment: `awk` allows you to use a regexp as record separator (RS). You could read the file into an array and sort it with `asort`, for example.

Comment: Could you please provide the syntax? My `awk` is bit rusty. The issue is that I want to _merge_ the two text files into one. How do I do that?

Comment: The basic idea is to read both files into an array and sort it. If the files are very large, however, that would not be a valid strategy.

Comment: Could you please provide answer with some pointers? Like changing the RS and storing the matched text block into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[FNR] ORS $0}' file1 file2
# ::id 10
# ::snt Yes !

# ::id 10
# ::snt No !

# ::id 11
# ::snt said Lion .

# ::id 11
# ::snt said Monkey .

# ::id 12
# ::snt Yes yes !

# ::id 12
# ::snt No no !

# ::id 13
# ::snt said Tiger .

# ::id 13
# ::snt said Donkey .
```

The above reads the contents of the files one paragraph at a time into array `a[]` where paragraphs are blocks of text separated by chains of blank lines (courtesy of setting `RS` to null). When it reads the first file it just stores them in an array `a[1..number of paragraphs]` and then after it's read all of file1 into `a[]` when it reads the 2nd file it prints the the corresponding paragraph from file1 (`a[paragraph number]`) first and then the current paragraph from file2.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I updated my question with more information. But I guess you understood the _merge_ aspect of this.

Comment: If you get some time, I would really appreciate explanation of how it works. Always a pleasure to learn :-)

Comment: I added an explanation at the end. I recommend the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Say: `awk -f merge.awk file1 file2`

```
BEGIN { RS="" }
{ ARR[NR] = $0 }
END {
    n = asort(ARR);
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        print ARR[i];
}
```

Comment: This may sort more than intended as it is going to use the entire contents of the paragraph while sorting. You could store by id in `ARR` (and append to the value) to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks! Very much helpful. However, the asort function messes up the order of files. I want first block from file1 and second block from file 2. But it returns in reverse order. I tried reordering the file but no luck. It looks like the `asort` function sorts the array as string. So if the block from `file2` is _stringwise_ smaller then it will appear first. Any pointers on how to fix this?

Comment: err, any pointers on how to store both the block and the id? Can I process a record twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `sed` and `sort`:

```
 sed '/# ::id/N;s/\n/ /;/^$/d' file1 file2 | sort -s -n -k3,3 | sed 's/\(# ::snt.*\)/\n\1\n/'
```

The first `sed` part is joining line next line together with the one containing `# ::id` and delete the empty line.

The result is then sorted by the id number of the expression `# ::id xx` (3rd parameter).

At last the line are cut in 2 pieces where the `# ::snt` is found

Comment: Thanks! However, there are few more lines (unstructured) after the `# ::snt` line. How do I capture all of those?

Answer (score 0):

this matches records by the ids numbers in case they are not aligned in both files

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS= 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next}
                            {printf "%s\n\n%s\n\n",a[$1],$0}' file1 file2

# ::id 10
# ::snt Yes !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 10
# ::snt No !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...

# ::id 11
# ::snt said Lion .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 11
# ::snt said Monkey .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...

# ::id 12
# ::snt Yes yes !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 12
# ::snt No no !
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...

# ::id 13
# ::snt said Tiger .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 1...

# ::id 13
# ::snt said Donkey .
 ...multiple lines of unstructured data from file 2...
```

can be enhanced to catch missing records in file2 as well.